# TomEE Exception when trying to access datasource from JAX-WS

Tags: java, jdbc, jax-ws, datasource, apache-tomee

I have class called ConnectionManager

```
public class ConnectionManager{
   public static getDBConnection()
  {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    DataSource ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/mydb");
    return ds.getConnection();
 }
```

}

When it tried to call this class from jsp page, servlet, jax-rs restful service, it just works fine.

However, I go the following exception when i try to call ConnectionManager.getDBConnection() from JAX-WS web service:

```
Name [comp/env/jdbc/mydb] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
```

Please note that i defined the Resource inside TomEE_HOME/conf/context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/mydb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           username="user" password="pass" 
           driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
           url="jdbc:sqlserver://10.x.x.x:xxxx;databaseName=MyDBName"/>
```

Please advice.